# Is there a way of creating symbols with a 3D look for 2D maps?

Tags: symbology

I have tried looking for SVG icons that look more 3D.

All I need is the circle represented by the Simple Symbol. Would be nicer if it had a more 3D look.

[image]

Like this perhaps:

[image]

Comment: Where did you look? There's lots of free SVG clipart sites, and searching for "ball" on one of them found me something that might be a starting point for you. http://www.clker.com/clipart-6493.html Edit in `inkscape` or any other SVG vector editor to change colours etc. Searching there for "pin" gets me this: http://www.clker.com/clipart-location-marker.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK Thanks. I was hoping to get an image without having to edit in inkscape. But it looks like that is what that needs to be done.